# Installing Qiskit Error: Building wheel for ecos error

Tags: qiskit, programming

[image]

How can I fix this error? I am installing the newest version of Qiskit.

Comment: Hi, can you show more of the error message please?

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to be reported by various users as per the Qiskit GitHub repository. Could you please try the following steps.

1. Install Anaconda
2. Create a python 3.7 environment: conda create --name your_env python=3.7
3. conda activate your_env
4. pip install qiskit

You can report the specific details of the issues in the following GitHub repository issue log if it is persisting after following these steps.

[Qiskit GitHub Repository Issue Log](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/197)

Comment: thanks sir  it working very well no w